# Any Utility Api/Method to batch processing of Set/List in java?

Tags: java

Assume i have a list of items or set of items which has 100 items in it.

I want to process the list or the given set based on the number of items needs to be processed per batch.

Ex, if i pass the parameter as 10, 10 items needs to be returned per iteration or per loop.

Is there a good api/method or any utility which can be achieved in java ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for something like

```
<Type> Collection<Collection<Type>> slice(Collection<Type> source, int size)
```

I'm quite sure [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) must contain something like that, but can't find it back. Well, I found it : it's [`Iterables#partition(...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29). In the same spirit, there must be an equivalent feature in [Apache commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).